# Calling super for higher order classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to skip classes in the method resolution order when calling for methods?

For example,
super().super()

Comment: In my own personal opinion, that's WAY less maintainable than just writing `GrandParentClass.method( self, a, b, c )`.  If you really are targeting a specific ancestor, than you have lost the benefit of `super` anyway.  Right?

Comment: Hmm.. why do you believe that?

Comment: `super` is a name in the built-in scope, not an attribute.

Comment: Readability.  The advantage of `super` is that you don't have to rewrite the code if you change the base class.  But when you write `super().super()`, someone reading your code is going to have to go digging to find what the grandparent class is.  It seems to me that, if you are so tightly tied to your ancestry that you know about something in the grandparent, you might as well just make it explicit.  My opinion, your mileage may vary.

Comment: You *can* skip one or more classes by providing an appropriate first argument to `super`, but you need to know which class to use. For example, with an MRO like `[A, B, C, D]`, using `super(C).foo()` in `A.foo` will skip `B.foo`. (That is, skipping requires an absolute starting point, not a relative one.)

Comment: The real advantage of `super` is that it handles multiple inheritance correctly, not readability or DRY.

Comment: Interesting guys, thank you

Comment: Arew you sure, chepner have you seen the answers? An absolute starting point is not required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super
that lead me to this code

```
class A:
    def show(self):
        print("A")

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print("B")

    def s(self):
        return super()

class C(B):
    def __init__(self):
        super().s().show()

c = C()
c
```

See that **super** returns a proxy object that seems not to have the super method (because i tried and the interpreter told me it doesn't). But you do have the others methods from the class, so this way I could get a proxy from its grandparent to use its methods

Comment: *"seems not to have the super method"* There is no `super` method at all, that is why you write `super()` and not `self.super()`.

Comment: works in python 3.8, which python version are you using?

Comment: No, `self.super()` does not work in any version of Python (unless you write a class with your own method named `super`). `super` is not a method, it is a built-in function like `print` or `len`. You can't write `super().super()` for the same reason you can't write `super().print()` to print something out.

Comment: This is the perfect solution, thanks for reading the docs

Answer (score 1):

`super()` in the class definition for `FooClass` is shorthand for `super(FooClass, self)`. Using this, we can do this:

```
class Grandparent:
    def test(self):
        print('grandparent gets called')


class Parent(Grandparent):
    def test(self):
        super().test()
        print('parent gets skipped')


class Child(Parent):
    def test(self):
        super(Parent, self).test()
        print('child gets called')
```

This "cheats" the MRO by checking the parent's superclass instead of the child's superclass.

Comment: Adn tbh this code is pretty pointless, because you;ve hardcoded the Parent class in Child...

Comment: @Malemna You could write `super(self.__class__.__bases__[0], self)` instead, if you really want. But I think writing `Parent` is clearer, and if you are dependent on using the grandparent class's behaviour rather than the parent class's behaviour then you are already throwing "best practices" out of the window anyway.

Comment: although it should mention this is python 2

Comment: @kaya3 That would break multiple inheritance, why is the reason `super` exists in the first place.